# Update the data of the parent window from the child window. C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

There is a parent window, a page is declared in it, there is a (Edit) button on the page. By clicking on the button, a window will open, after it is closed, the data in the parent window should be updated.

**ViewModel Parent Window**

```
public class MasterWinViewModel : Notify
{
    private object _curentPage;

    public object CurentPage
    {
        get { return _curentPage; }
        set
        {
            _curentPage = value;
            SignalChanged("CurentPage");
        }
    }

    public UserApi ProfileUser
    { 
        get => profileUser;
        set 
        {
            profileUser = value;
            SignalChanged("ProfileUser");
        } 
    }
    public CustomCommand Main { get; set; }
    public CustomCommand Help { get; set; }
    public CustomCommand Search { get; set; }
    public CustomCommand MyMediaLibrary { get; set; }
    public CustomCommand Profile { get; set; }
    public CustomCommand Test { get; set; }

    private UserApi profileUser;

    public MasterWinViewModel()
    {

        Task.Run(GetUserId);

       


        Test = new CustomCommand(() =>
        {
            Test nn = new Test();
            nn.Show();
        });

        Main = new CustomCommand(() =>
        {
            CurentPage = new MainPage();
            SignalChanged("CurentPage");
        });

        Help = new CustomCommand(() =>
        {
            CurentPage = new HelpPage();
            SignalChanged("CurentPage");
        });

        Search = new CustomCommand(() =>
        {
            CurentPage = new SearchPage();
            SignalChanged("CurentPage");
        });

        MyMediaLibrary = new CustomCommand(() =>
        {
            CurentPage = new MyMediaLibraryPage();
            SignalChanged("CurentPage");
        });

        Profile = new CustomCommand(() =>
        {
            CurentPage = new ProfilePage();
            SignalChanged("CurentPage");
        });
    }

    public async Task GetUserId()
    {
        Task.Delay(200).Wait();
        var t = SingInWindowViewModel.UsId;
        var result = await Api.GetAsync<UserApi>(t, "User");
        ProfileUser = result;
        SignalChanged("ProfileUser");
    }
   
    

}
```

**ViewModel pages**

```
public class ProfilePageViewModel : Notify
{
    private CustomCommand selectedAlbum;
    private List<AlbumApi> albums;

    public CustomCommand SelectedAlbum
    {
        get => selectedAlbum;
        set
        {
            selectedAlbum = value;
            SignalChanged();
        }
    }

    public List<AlbumApi> Albums 
    {
        get => albums;
        set 
        {
            albums = value;
            SignalChanged("Albums");
        } 
    }

    public CustomCommand NewAlbum { get; set; }
    public UserApi ProfileUser { get; set; }
    public CustomCommand Edit { get; set; }
    public CustomCommand EditAlbum { get; set; }
    public CustomCommand DeleteAlbum { get; set; }
    public CustomCommand Refresh { get; set; }


    public ProfilePageViewModel()
    {
        Task.Run(GetUserId);
        Task.Run(GetAlbumsList);

        Refresh = new CustomCommand(() =>
        {
            Task.Run(GetUserId);
            Task.Run(GetAlbumsList);
        });


        Edit = new CustomCommand(() =>
        {
            EditUserWindow euw = new EditUserWindow();
            euw.ShowDialog();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Task.Run(GetUserId);
            
        });

        NewAlbum = new CustomCommand(() =>
        {
            AddAlbumWindow albumWindow = new AddAlbumWindow();
            albumWindow.Show();
        });
    }


    public async Task GetUserId()
    {
        var t = SingInWindowViewModel.UsId;
        var result = await Api.GetAsync<UserApi>(t, "User");
        ProfileUser = result;
        SignalChanged("ProfileUser");
    }

    public async Task GetAlbumsList()
    {
        var result = await Api.GetListAsync<AlbumApi[]>("Album");
        Albums = new List<AlbumApi>(result);
        SignalChanged("Albums");
    }


    public void Load()
    {
        Task.Run(GetUserId);
        Task.Run(GetAlbumsList);
    }
}
```

**ViewModel editing windows**

```
public class EditUserWindowViewModel : Notify
{
    private BitmapImage image;
    public BitmapImage Image 
    { 
        get => image;
        set 
        {
            image = value;
            SignalChanged("Image");
        } 
    }

    public UserApi EditUser { get; set; }
    public CustomCommand SelectImage { get; set; }
    public CustomCommand SaveUser { get; set; }

    public EditUserWindowViewModel()
    {
        Task.Run(GetUserId);

        SaveUser = new CustomCommand(() =>
        {
            Task.Run(EditUsers);
            foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
            {
                if (window.DataContext == this)
                {
                    
                    CloseWin(window);
                }
            }
            
        });

        string directory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        SelectImage = new CustomCommand(() =>
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    var info = new FileInfo(ofd.FileName);
                    Image = GetImageFromPath(ofd.FileName);
                    EditUser.Image = $"/Resource/{info.Name}";
                    var newPath = directory.Substring(0, directory.Length) + EditUser.Image;
                    if (!File.Exists(newPath))
                        File.Copy(ofd.FileName, newPath, true);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Code error: Image Error", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void CloseWin(object obj)
    {
        Window win = obj as Window;
        win.Close();
    }

    private BitmapImage GetImageFromPath(string url)
    {
        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
        img.BeginInit();
        img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        img.UriSource = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
        img.EndInit();
        return img;
    }

    public async Task EditUsers()
    {
        await Api.PutAsync<UserApi>(EditUser, "User");
    }

    public async Task GetUserId()
    {
        var t = SingInWindowViewModel.UsId;
        var result = await Api.GetAsync<UserApi>(t, "User");
        EditUser = result;
        SignalChanged("EditUser");
    }

    
    
}
```

I tried to update the data after closing the child window, but this did not solve the problem. Because the child window does not know about the parent window.

Comment: Which child window is supposed to update what? This is the user's profile being edited?

Comment: You should change Task.Delay(200).Wait(); to await Task.Delay(200);  Almost always a bad idea to use .Wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use event on each page objects.

Below code is minimum example for it.

**ViewModel Parent Window**

```
public class MasterWinViewModel : Notify
{
    private object _curentPage;

    public object CurentPage
    {
        get { return _curentPage; }
        set
        {
            _curentPage = value;
            SignalChanged("CurentPage");
        }
    }
    
    public CustomCommand Profile { get; set; }       

    public MasterWinViewModel()
    {        
        Profile = new CustomCommand(() =>
        {
            ProfilePageViewModel profilepagevm = new ProfilePageViewModel();

            ProfilePageViewModel.OnEventFire += (sender, data) => 
            {
                //sender = profilepage
                //data = data object from profilepage
                //Do something with sent data.              
            }               

            ProfilePage profilepage = new ProfilePage();

            // Set DataContext. Not sure because I don't know ProfilePage's exact implementation.
            profilepage.DataContext = profilepagevm;

            CurentPage = profilepage;

            SignalChanged("CurentPage");
        });
    }      
}
```

**ProfilePageViewModel**

```
public class ProfilePageViewModel : Notify
{    
    public delegate void EventDelegate(object sender, object data);
    
    public event EventDelegate OnEventFire = null;
    
    public ProfilePageViewModel()
    {
        
    } 
    
    public void EventFireMethod(object data) 
    {
        //Fire Event
        OnEventFire?.Invoke(this, data);
    }   
}
```

After calling `EventFireMethod` in ProfilePage class, callback method will be invoked.

In this way, you can send data between parent window and child page object.

Comment: Error: Severity Code Description Project File String Suppression Status
Error CS1061 "ProfilePage" does not contain the definition of "OnEventFire", and an available extension method "OnEventFire" could not be found that accepts the type "ProfilePage" as the first argument (perhaps the using directive or assembly reference was omitted). SpotyClient C:\Users\pokim\source\repos\SpotifyServer\SpotyClient\ViewModel\MasterWinViewModel.cs 89 Active

Comment: Maybe so  `ProfilePageViewModel profilepage = new ProfilePageViewModel();`?

Comment: @memes Yes, I don't have your `ProfilePage` class implementation, so I used `ProfilePageViewModel` class instead. If you have to send data in `ProfilePage` class, you can create delegate and event in it too.